# Apply RemoveRange with different List with common identifier

Tags: c#, list

In my case I had two different lists, with a common identifier.How to remove list2 from list1 on basis of some common property. 
Thinking I have two list.

```
class A
{
public int Id {get;set;}
public int Roll{get;set;}
}

class B
{
public int Id {get;set;}
public int Ro{get;set;}
}

var Acollection = new List<A>();
Acollection.Add(new A{Id=1,Roll=1});
Acollection.Add(new A{Id=2,Roll=2});

var Bcollection = new List<B>();
Bcollection.Add(new B{Id=1,Ro=3});
Bcollection.Add(new B{Id=3,Ro=2});
```

Now I want to remove B from A where Id same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`List<T>.RemoveAll(Predicate<T>)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdka673a%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
Acollection.RemoveAll(a => Bcollection.Any(b => b.Id == a.Id));
```

To speed things up, you could put the ids in a hash table first:

```
var ids = new HashSet<int>(Bcollection.Select(b => b.Id));
Acollection.RemoveAll(a => ids.Contains(a.Id));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use LINQ [`Where`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb549418%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method like this:

```
Acollection =
    Acollection
    .Where(a => Bcollection.All(b => a.Id != b.Id))
    .ToList();
```

If `BCollection` is large and you are worried about performance, then you can use a [`HashSet`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb359438(v=vs.110).aspx) like this:

```
HashSet<int> bad_ids = new HashSet<int>();

Bcollection.ForEach(b => bad_ids.Add(b.Id));

Acollection =
    Acollection
    .Where(a => !bad_ids.Contains(a.Id))
    .ToList();
```